# В какой контейнер положить или как разместить datagridview и listview?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма которая разворачивается во весь экран, как мне разместить datagridview и listview чтобы когда форма разворачивалась,datagridview и listview не мешая другу другу также развернулись на весь экран?
Вот что у меня получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот что нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно используйте привязки Anchor (из можно найти в свойствах, уберите у listview левый и добавите правый) или используйте панели, которые так же помогают формировать UI содержимое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов использовать правильно привязки Anchor.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй из возможных вариантов, добавить TableLayoutPanel с двумя колонками и со свойствами `AutoSize = True; AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink; Anchor = лево, низ, право`. В каждую колонку добавить свой контрол DataGrid или ListView так же задав им свойства `Dock = Fill`.